# Creating a sliced Circle in HTML Canvas

Tags: html, css, canvas

I am trying to create a circle with a gradient in an HTML canvas but don't really know where to start. I have played around but haven't managed to make any headway thus far.

I have managed to create the circle in CSS, but I cannot slice it as the gradient absolutely must stay at the same place on the circle and with CSS it requires rotation in order to slice up a circle...

Here is what I did in CSS and HTML:

### HTML

```
<div id="progress"></div>
```

### CSS

```
#progress {
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 212px;
    height: 212px;
    margin: 14px;
    background: #5c00d2;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(45deg,  #5c00d2 0%, #d586f4 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left bottom, right top, color-stop(0%,#5c00d2), color-stop(100%,#d586f4));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg,  #5c00d2 0%,#d586f4 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(45deg,  #5c00d2 0%,#d586f4 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(45deg,  #5c00d2 0%,#d586f4 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(45deg,  #5c00d2 0%,#d586f4 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#5c00d2', endColorstr='#d586f4',GradientType=1 );
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 5px 3px rgba(5,71,110,0.5), inset 0px 0px 30px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 5px 3px rgba(5,71,110,0.5), inset 0px 0px 30px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 5px 3px rgba(5,71,110,0.5), inset 0px 0px 30px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}
```

### Result

[image: Circle with Gradient]

### Update

I haven't made it very clear what I am trying to achieve here, See the following:

https://css-tricks.com/css-pie-timer/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by drawing on the canvas. The following code will get you going, but you can take a look at http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/ for more info.

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="144" height="144"></canvas>

<script>
function convertToRadians(degree) {
    return degree*(Math.PI/180);
}

var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
var centerX = canvas.width / 2;
var centerY = canvas.height / 2;
var sections = 6;
var radius = 70;

context.beginPath();
context.lineWidth = 2;
context.arc(radius + context.lineWidth, radius + context.lineWidth, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
var grd = context.createLinearGradient(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
grd.addColorStop(0, '#8ED6FF');   
grd.addColorStop(1, '#004CB3');
context.fillStyle = grd;
context.fill();

for (i = 0; i < sections; i++){
    context.save();
    context.beginPath();
    context.moveTo(radius + context.lineWidth, radius + context.lineWidth);
    if (i) context.rotate(convertToRadians((i)*365/sections-context.lineWidth));
    context.lineTo(radius + context.lineWidth, (radius * 45) + context.lineWidth);
    context.strokeStyle = '#ffffff';
    context.stroke();
    context.restore();
}
</script>
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LVXyKw

## UPDATE TO ACCOMMODATE COMMENTS

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="200" height="200"></canvas>

function convertToRadians(degree) {
    return degree*(Math.PI);
}

var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

function showProgress(percent){
    console.log(percent);
    var centerX = canvas.width / 2;
    var centerY = canvas.height / 2;
    var sections = 6;
    var radius = 100;

    context.beginPath();
    context.arc(centerX, centerY, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
    var grd = context.createLinearGradient(canvas.width, 0, 0, canvas.height);
    grd.addColorStop(0, '#d586f4');   
    grd.addColorStop(1, '#5c00d2');
    context.fillStyle = grd;
    context.fill();

    context.beginPath();
    if (percent){
        var amt = ((2 / 100) * percent) + 1.5;
        if (amt > 2) amt = amt - 2;
        context.arc(centerX, centerY, radius, amt * Math.PI, 1.5 * Math.PI, false); //25%
    } else context.arc(centerX, centerY, radius, 0 * Math.PI, 2 * Math.PI, false); //0%

    context.lineWidth = (radius - .3) * 2;
    context.strokeStyle = '#ffffff';
    context.stroke();
}

var timer = setInterval(function(){ runTimer() }, 20);
var t = 0;

function runTimer(){
    if (t == 101) stopTimer();
    context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    showProgress(t);
    t++;
}

function stopTimer() {
    clearInterval(myVar);
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vOQZRg

Comment: This is fantastic thank you, however, I wasn't very clear in my question. I do not want to slice up the circle, I would like the circle to act like a progress bar. See here: http://kimmobrunfeldt.github.io/progressbar.js/.

Comment: The only difference to that example is that I do not want to just shrink the stroke of the circle, I want the whole circle to reduce. And I need to be able to animate it...

Comment: See the following: https://css-tricks.com/css-pie-timer/. That is the sort of shape I need :-)

Comment: Does thier demo not work for your needs? http://codepen.io/HugoGiraudel/pen/BHEwo Is it the gradient that shifts around?

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work. If you paste the following into the backgrounf part you will see why `linear-gradient(45deg,  #5c00d2 0%,#d586f4 100%)`

Comment: Alright, take a look at that. I did it in such a way where all you need to do from your script is pass the percentage (not converted to a decimal and not with the %) and it will write out to your canvas. So 50% would be passed as showProgress(50);

Comment: That is absolutely brilliant and exactly what I am looking for!!! Finally, would you mind changing the gradient start and end points to ensure they match my example? I don't know where to do this myself...

Comment: Sorry, I have one last question (I hope), if you are still willing to assist me. I have implemented your code on my progress bar but have realised that during the animation, the background of the canvas is white and overlays anything behind it. This circle is being placed over another graphic so I need the canvas to have a transparent background. It currently does, but not whilst it is animating... Let me know if you can help :-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84529/discussion-between-madness-and-ben-carey).

Answer (score -2):

Hey there not quite sure what your looking for but take a look at this hope it helps :)

```
  background: 
    linear-gradient(36deg, #272b66 42.34%, transparent 42.34%) 0 0,
    linear-gradient(72deg, #2d559f 75.48%, transparent 75.48%) 0 0,
    linear-gradient(-36deg, #9ac147 42.34%, transparent 42.34%) 100% 0,
    linear-gradient(-72deg, #639b47 75.48%, transparent 75.48%) 100% 0, 
    linear-gradient(36deg, transparent 57.66%, #e1e23b 57.66%) 100% 100%,
    linear-gradient(72deg, transparent 24.52%, #f7941e 24.52%) 100% 100%,
    linear-gradient(-36deg, transparent 57.66%, #662a6c 57.66%) 0 100%,
    linear-gradient(-72deg, transparent 24.52%, #9a1d34 24.52%) 0 100%, 
    #43a1cd linear-gradient(#ba3e2e, #ba3e2e) 50% 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 50% 50%;
  transition: 1s;
}
```

http://codepen.io/thebabydino/pen/hkxGp